# Best way to store an array considering all matches like query?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need some tips to achieve something im working on.
I have a json and i have to store it in snowflake.
Everything is easy as it sound, except for an array field.

In that jason i have an array with an undefined number of strings and i dont know which is the best way to store it.

After the insertion, i have to query this array looking for more than one array coincidence.

My first idea is to store it as an array with the type ARRAY and then, in the query, add multiple WHERE clauses for each of the elements that should match.

Example:

Considering an element with this array:

["one", "two", "trhee"]

...WHERE array_contains('one', fieldReference) AND ...WHERE array_contains('two', fieldReference)...

I guess this works, but i dont know if this is the best way to achieve it.
I dont even know if the best way to store this values is an array.

Could you give me any tips?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought you might be able to use the ARRAY_OVERLAP( ) function, but it appears that will provide you with a TRUE if there are any matches, not all elements match.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/arrays_overlap.html

---

What I think you can use is the ARRAY_INTERSECTION( ) function, and test the results of that function to your search array for equality with the array (list) of values you are searching for.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/array_intersection.html

Example as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE array_demo (id INTEGER, array1 ARRAY);

INSERT INTO array_demo (id, array1)
    SELECT 1, array_construct(1, 2) UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, array_construct(2, 3) UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, array_construct(3, 4) UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, array_construct(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

SET search_array = '[2,3]';

SELECT *
FROM   array_demo
WHERE  array_intersection(array1, parse_json($search_array)) = parse_json($search_array);
--returns two records, ids 2 and 4
```

Comment: Is this a heavy operation? I have to to search in a 10 gb table with millions of rows, and i dont know how much intensive would be a parse json over each of the rows.